# selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException - Google Image Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using the code from this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rolba/ai-nimals/blob/master/ai_nimals_scrapper.py) to scrape some images from Google Image Search results. However, there is one `try-exception` block where my code gives this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException
>
> D:\Downloads\google_images_downloader-master\google_images_downloader-master>[19680:952:0326/213123.951:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100

The following is the code block:

```
number_of_scrolls = int((num_requested / 400) + 10)
for _ in range(number_of_scrolls):
   for __ in range(10):
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000000)")
      time.sleep(0.2)
   time.sleep(0.5)
   try: 
      wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
      element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Show more results']")))
      element.click()  
   except Exception as e:   
       print ("Less images found:", e)
       break
```

P.S. I'm using Chrome as my webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are facing issue becausse I have copied same code from link you provided and its working fine for me. Only I have made couple of changes

1. insted of firefox, I have used chrome
2. Not able to search Więcej wyników on `https://www.google.com/search?q=Poecile%20montanus%20bird&source=lnms&tbm=isch`. Getting SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc4' for a `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Więcej wyników']").click()` due ASCII char. To avoid this error i have changed xpath to  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='W']").click()` due to this we are getting `('Less images found:', NoSuchElementException())` . Please check screenshot for more details

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   import os
   import json
   import urllib3
   import time
   import shutil

   searched_test_array = [
       # "Parus major bird",
       "Poecile montanus bird",
       # "Carduelis flammea bird",
       # "Parus cristatus bird",
       # "Carduelis spinus bird",
       # "Turdus iliacus bird",
       # "Dryocopus martius bird",
       # "Dendrocopos major bird",
       # "Picus canus bird",
       # "Picus viridis bird",
       # "Dendrocopos medius bird",
       # "Dendrocopos minor bird",    #NOK
       # "Carduelis chloris bird",
       # "Pyrrhula pyrrhula bird",
       # "Columba livia bird",
       "Coccothraustes coccothraustes bird",
       # "Carduelis cannabina bird",
       # "Passer montanus bird",
       # "Larus canus bird",
       # "Larus argentatus bird",
       "Parus caeruleus bird",
       # "Regulus regulus bird",
       # "Buteo buteo bird",
       # "Certhia familiaris bird",
       # "Certhia brachydactyla bird",
       # "Emberiza calandra bird bird",
       # "Corvus frugilegus bird",
       # "Accipiter gentilis bird",
       # "Bombycilla garrulus bird",
       # "Fringilla montifringilla bird",
       # "Corvus monedula bird",
       # "Turdus merula bird",
       # "Sitta europaea bird",
       # "Accipiter nisus bird",
       # "Corvus corax bird",
       # "Turdus pilaris bird",
       # "Emberiza schoeniclus bird",
       # "Aegithalos caudatus bird",
       # "Erithacus rubicola bird",
       # "Carduelis flavirostris bird",
       # "Streptopelia decaocto bird",
       # "Parus palustris bird",
       # "Parus ater bird",
       # "Pica pica bird",
       # "Lanius excubitor bird",
       # "Troglodytes troglodytes bird",
       "Carduelis carduelis bird",
       # "Sturnus vulgaris bird",

       # "Garrulus glandarius bird",
       # "Emberiza citrinella bird",

       # "Corvus corone bird",
       # "Passer domesticus bird",
       # "Panurus biarmicus bird",
       # "Fringilla coelebs bird",
       # "Larus ridibundus bird"
   ]

   num_requested = 1000

   # adding path to geckodriver to the OS environment variable
   os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.getcwd()
   download_path = os.getcwd() + "/Downloads"


   def main():
   print ("Scrapping started")

   # Create Donwload patch or delete existing!
   if not os.path.exists(download_path):
       os.makedirs(download_path)
   # else:
   #     shutil.rmtree(download_path)
   #     os.makedirs(download_path)

   # Iterate over search array
   for searchtext in searched_test_array:

       # Create class patch of delete existing
       searchedTextDir = os.path.join(download_path, searchtext.replace(" ", "_"))
       if not os.path.exists(searchedTextDir):
           os.makedirs(searchedTextDir)
       # else:
       #     shutil.rmtree(searchedTextDir)
       #     os.makedirs(searchedTextDir)

       # Prepare search URL. searchtext is a name of a class.
       url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchtext + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
       # Start Firefox

       driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
       # Open URL
       driver.get(url)

       extensions = {"jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"}
       img_count = 0
       downloaded_img_count = 0

       # I have to do some magic math to make web browser scroll down the search box.
       number_of_scrolls = int((num_requested / 400) + 10)
       for _ in range(number_of_scrolls):
           for __ in range(10):
               # And scroll scroll scroll to let Google Json load  images
               driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000000)")
               time.sleep(0.2)
           # to load next 400 images
           time.sleep(0.5)
           try:
               # Look for a button down the page for more search results.
               # For English version use: //input[@value='Show more results']

                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='W']").click()

           except Exception as e:
               print ("Less images found:", e)
               break

       # Get URLs of all images on the page
       imges = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"rg_meta")]')
       print ("Total images:", len(imges), "\n")

       # Start iterating over found URLs
       for img in imges:
           img_count += 1
           img_url = json.loads(img.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ou"]
           img_type = json.loads(img.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ity"]
           print ("Downloading image", img_count, ": ", img_url, img_type)
           try:
               # Thy to save image on HDD
               if img_type not in extensions:
                   img_type = "jpg"
               http = urllib3.PoolManager()

               # Write image to hdd. Don't forget about timeout!
               response = http.request('GET', img_url, timeout=2)
               f = open(searchedTextDir + "/" + str(downloaded_img_count) + "." + img_type, "wb")
               f.write(response.data)
               f.close
               downloaded_img_count += 1
           except Exception as e:
               print ("Download failed:", e)
           finally:
               print
           if downloaded_img_count >= num_requested:
               break

       print ("Total downloaded: ", downloaded_img_count, "/", img_count)
       driver.quit()
       time.sleep(0.5)

   print ("Scrapping done")


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

[image]

**To click on show more** `Show more results`

```
add  for _ in range(number_of_scrolls):
        for __ in range(10):
            # And scroll scroll scroll to let Google Json load  images
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000000)")
            time.sleep(0.2)
        # to load next 400 images
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='mye4qd']").click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: for me I had to give `find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Show more results']")` for English. And moreover in the screenshot I see that for you also total images downloaded it shows 0/0 for all cases

Comment: error `Message: element not interactable`, that's why its getting 0/0 images just like in your screenshot as well, in the output

Comment: no you are getting 0 images because locator which you are using in your code have 0 matching elements. you neeed to make sure you aare passing correct locators. Thee program on a git have old locators which is not valid now

Comment: Any idea how do I get ro user the updated outr corrected locators? Not so experienced with selenium

Comment: not sure but I think might be worth to check with git owner what exactly changed

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch TimeoutException with:

```
except Exception as e:
```

You should use:

```
except TimeoutException:
```

And also you'll have to import that exception from Selenium:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```